# PHP/MYSQL AJAX Chat

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, comet, chat

Looking for an open source php/mysql ajax chat room (not 1-to-1 private chat). What would you guys recommend?

I am going to need to make hundreds of instances of the chat room (eg. each user group has their own exclusive chat room)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at phpFreeChat. It's an active project which is easy to implement.

http://www.phpfreechat.net/

Comment: hmm, stores messages and info in files... I'm going to be making hundreds of instances of this so at the least need to store stuff in DB

Comment: you can change the container_type to Mysql instead of the File default

Answer (score 0):

I think Ajax Chat is great. https://blueimp.net/ajax/

Very customizable appearance and integration into your site.

I was hunting for a solution that fit in well with my existing layout... I thought phpfreechat was difficult... you may have more luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help you, its a very detailed article for your problem.

[group-chat-in-php-with-ajax-jquery-mysql](http://subinsb.com/group-chat-in-php-with-ajax-jquery-mysql)