# Where can I get a PHP / MYSQL chat room application

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, chat

My question is an elaboration of this one: 
[PHP/MYSQL AJAX Chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093251/php-mysql-ajax-chat)

I have a 100 chat rooms which I need to make. Is there a php/mysql based chat system that would do something like this?

phpFreeChat is mentioned, but from what I understand, I have to (manually) download and install the application 100 times in different folders to use that.
That obviously is not going to work.

Does anybody have any experience on this issue? Ideally, the chat room would be a push-based system, or anything that doesn't make too many calls on the server.

Thanks

Comment: SO is for "how do I build," not "where do I find" :)

Comment: maybe. i'm asking because there have been multiple questions like this (see above) before. also, people commonly ask for jquery plugins, advice on choosing IDEs, etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used [ajchat](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ajchat/) in the past. The fact that it is basic and does the core stuff of a chat app made me stick with it. The app is very simple, which is part of the appeal for me. You can easily understand how it works and modify it to suit your needs.