# best php based chat application

Tags: php, ajax

I am new to php. I want to embed a chat application in my website. Does anyone know which chat application will be best suitable for my website which will run on my *intranet*. The chat application must be free of cost and `PHP` based.

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question has been asked before in various variations: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+chat you will find plenty of good answers there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Where can I get a PHP / MYSQL chat room application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230619/where-can-i-get-a-php-mysql-chat-room-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make your own application, you will need for sure AJAX or some third parties like Adobe Flash. There are also plenty of free open source projects on which you can base your own. The only free one I ever used is [HelpCenter Live](http://www.helpcenterlive.com/).

Answer (score 0):

[MQTTCHAT](https://mqttchat.telifoun.com) is a php chat script that can be integrated to any php website.  it uses MQTT and websockets.