# Php Ajax chat coding

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to get the PHP coding for Ajax chat set up right for the site that I am building. However, every time that I think I have it correct and post it to the page that I want it on for my site, then click on the link for the page titled "Chat" it shows the code. 
Maybe it's because I am new to learning Php but I don't know what I am doing wrong with it. Has anyone else had this problem? Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Do you have PHP running on that machine? Is the type (php) added in apache config?

Comment: sounds like you dont have php installed/setup on your server if its showing you code

Comment: Please post the code which throws an error, it will be hard to try to hlp with only those information

Answer (score 1):

This question is asked here on this site:

[How to make a chat room script with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/772471/how-to-make-a-chat-room-script-with-php)

and here

[PHP/MYSQL AJAX Chat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093251/php-mysql-ajax-chat)

The rigor of the task is yours.